# Stacking multiple groups of columns at the same time

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to transform this DataFrame

```
         date  foo1  foo2  foo3  bar1  bar2  bar3
0  2018-06-01   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6
1  2018-06-02   1.1   1.2   1.3   1.4   1.5   1.6
```

into this one

```
         date  i  foo  bar
0  2018-06-01  1  0.1  0.4
1  2018-06-01  2  0.2  0.5
2  2018-06-01  3  0.3  0.6
3  2018-06-02  1  1.1  1.4
4  2018-06-02  2  1.2  1.5
5  2018-06-02  3  1.3  1.6
```

In other words: I want to stack the `fooX` and `barX` columns vertically, and add an `i` column containing the `X`'s.

As a first step, I've tried creating a MultiIndex to split the columns into two levels:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('foo', 'bar'), (1, 2, 3)],
                                   names=('metric', 'i'))
df.columns = index
```

However, this fails because the `date` column is not included in the MultiIndex:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Can I include a 1-level column in a 2-level MultiIndex? I've tried `index.append(pd.Index(['date'])`, but this drops the second level of the MultiIndex.

I'm probably approaching this problem from the wrong angle. Do you see any other ways to achieve this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very task of [`pd.wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ["foo", "bar"], i="date", j="id")

               foo  bar
date       id          
2018-06-01 1   0.1  0.4
2018-06-02 1   1.1  1.4
2018-06-01 2   0.2  0.5
2018-06-02 2   1.2  1.5
2018-06-01 3   0.3  0.6
2018-06-02 3   1.3  1.6
```

Comment: Very nice using this function :)

Comment: @jezrael thank you. You were absent for a while. Glad to see you back